# Add attribute only to first image of every post via functions.php

Tags: functions, images, customization

I would like to use a simple function in order to add a specific attribute (lets call it “example”) to the first image of every blog post, so that I don't have to do it manually in thousands of posts.

Unfortunately I'm not very good with preg_replace so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse317670_add_img_attribute' ); 

function wpse317670_add_img_attribute( $content ) { 
    $from = '/'.preg_quote('<img', '/').'/';
    $to = '<img example="example"';

    return preg_replace($from, $to, $content, 1);
}
```

This will add the `example="example"` to the first image found in every post content.

There is another option, without using regular expression (possibly much faster and will use less memory):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse317670_add_img_attribute' );

function wpse317670_add_img_attribute( $content ) {
    $from = '<img';
    $to   = '<img example="example"';

    $pos = strpos( $content, $from );
    if ( $pos !== false ) {
        return substr_replace( $content, $to, $pos, strlen( $from ) );
    }

    return $content;
}
```